# Pyspark Cosine similarity Invalid argument, not a string or column

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am trying to calculate cosine distances of 2 title and headline columns via using pre-trained bert model just like below

| title | headline | title_array | headline_array | arrayed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dance Gavin Dance bass player Tim Feerick dead at 34 | Prince Harry and Meghan Markle make secret visit to see Queen ahead of Invictus Games | ["Dance Gavin Dance bass player Tim Feerick dead at 34"] | ["Prince Harry and Meghan Markle make secret visit to see Queen ahead of Invictus Games"] | ["Dance Gavin Dance bass player Tim Feerick dead at 34", "Prince Harry and Meghan Markle make secret visit to see Queen ahead of Invictus Games"] |
|  |  |  |  |  |

```
# downloading bert
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')

from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

@udf(FloatType())
def cosine_similarity(sentence_embeddings, ind_a, ind_b):
    s = sentence_embeddings
    return np.dot(s[ind_a], s[ind_b]) / (np.linalg.norm(s[ind_a]) * np.linalg.norm(s[ind_b]))

#udf_bert = udf(cosine_similarity, FloatType())
''''
s0 = "our president is a good leader he will not fail"
s1 = "our president is not a good leader he will fail"
s2 = "our president is a good leader"
s3 = "our president will succeed"

sentences = [s0, s1, s2, s3]

sentence_embeddings = model.encode(sentences)

s = sentence_embeddings
print(f"{s0} <--> {s1}: {udf_bert(sentence_embeddings, 0, 1)}")
print(f"{s0} <--> {s2}: {cosine_similarity(sentence_embeddings, 0, 2)}")
print(f"{s0} <--> {s3}: {cosine_similarity(sentence_embeddings, 0, 3)}")
'''''

test_df = test_df.withColumn("Similarities", (cosine_similarity(model.encode(test_df.arrayed), 0, 1))
```

As we see from the example , algorithm takes concatenation of two array of strings and calculate distances of cosine among them.

When I only run the algorithm/function with the sample texts commented out , it is working. But when I try to apply it into my dataframe via registering as a udf and call with dataframe I am facing with the error below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-757165186581086> in <module>
     26 '''''
     27 
---> 28 test_df = test_df.withColumn("Similarities", f.lit(cosine_similarity(model.encode(test_df.arrayed), 0, 1)))

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in wrapper(*args)
    197         @functools.wraps(self.func, assigned=assignments)
    198         def wrapper(*args):
--> 199             return self(*args)
    200 
    201         wrapper.__name__ = self._name

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py in __call__(self, *cols)
    177         judf = self._judf
    178         sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
--> 179         return Column(judf.apply(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column)))
    180 
    181     # This function is for improving the online help system in the interactive interpreter.

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in _to_seq(sc, cols, converter)
     60     """
     61     if converter:
---> 62         cols = [converter(c) for c in cols]
     63     return sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(cols)
     64 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     60     """
     61     if converter:
---> 62         cols = [converter(c) for c in cols]
     63     return sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(cols)
     64 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in _to_java_column(col)
     44         jcol = _create_column_from_name(col)
     45     else:
---> 46         raise TypeError(
     47             "Invalid argument, not a string or column: "
     48             "{0} of type {1}. "

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [-0.29246375  0.02216947  0.610355   -0.02230968  0.61386955  0.15291359]
```

Answer (score 0):

The input of a UDF is a `Column` or a column name, that's why Spark is complaining `Invalid argument, not a string or column: [-0.29246375  0.02216947  0.610355   -0.02230968  0.61386955  0.15291359]`. You'll need to pass `arrayed` only, and refer `model` inside your UDF. Something like this

```py
@udf(FloatType())
def cosine_similarity(sentence_embeddings, ind_a, ind_b):
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
    model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
    s = model.encode(arrayed)
    return np.dot(s[ind_a], s[ind_b]) / (np.linalg.norm(s[ind_a]) * np.linalg.norm(s[ind_b]))

test_df = test_df.withColumn("Similarities", (cosine_similarity(test_df.arrayed, 0, 1))
```

Comment: `@udf(FloatType()) `

def cosine_similarity(sentence_embeddings, ind_a, ind_b):
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
    model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
    s = model.encode(arrayed)
    return np.dot(s[ind_a], s[ind_b]) / (np.linalg.norm(s[ind_a]) * np.linalg.norm(s[ind_b]))

when I try in your way I got an another error like below;

PythonException: 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentence_transformers'', from <command-4426171415048550>, line 12. Full traceback below:

Comment: You'll need to install `sentence_transformers` in all worker's node, not only driver